# Which archivers are capable of preserving timezone?

Tags: windows, archiving, time-zone

Recently I noticed that the files ZIPped on one of our servers in Japan being extracted on US server shows the future dates (+13 hours ahead). Experimentally I found that ZIP and RAR formats suffer from this issue.
Are there any other archivers storing dates in UTC format?

Comment: Well, isn't *that* time preserving ? At the same time it is 01 in Japan it is 13 hours ahead in USA .... at that same moment.

Comment: It's not the same moment.
Say file is created at 06:00PM at Jp (say GMT+9) and put into ZIP at the same time. At 6:05PM GMT+9  file is extracted on US server (local time is 02:05AM EST) and file date is set to 6:05PM EST. Total mess, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the docs of [7Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/), the archive formats tar, gzip2 and 7z (7Zip) use UTC timestamps. So these should work properly across timezones. However, in practice this will probably only work if the filesystems used also use UTC internally (such as most Unix filesystems and NTFS).